# How to use SlidingWindowSplitter in sktime

Tags: time-series, arima, sliding-window, sktime

I need to fit ARIMA model from `sktime` package. I want to use `SlidingWindowSplitter` from `sktime.forecasting.model_selection` but I don really understand how it works.
If I wanted to fit a simple ARIMA I would do this

```
...
model = ARIMA(order = (p, d, q)).fit(y_train)
y_pred, y_conf = model.predict(fh, return_pred_int=True)
```

But how that works with the SlidingWindowSplitter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```py
from sktime.forecasting.all import *
from sktime.forecasting.model_evaluation import evaluate

y = load_airline()
forecaster = ARIMA()
cv = SlidingWindowSplitter()
out = evaluate(forecaster, cv, y)
```

Comment: The following issue rises ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sktime.forecasting.model_evaluation```

Comment: Oops, yes, forgot that that functionality is still only on `master` and not on the latest release yet!